# How to add a solution in SharePoint when the UAC is Enabled?

Tags: sharepoint, uac, solution

I use stsadm-o addsolution -filename "mySolution" to install a solution, but when the UAC(User Account Control) is enabled, a "Access Denied" exception will be thrown.
I want to know how to add a solution with UAC enabled?

Note: I cannot use runas administrator, for it's cannot be invoked by third assemblies.

Update: I just want to use C# to implement Runas Administrator.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What are 'third assemblies'?  And what do they have to do with stsadm?

Comment: Are you saying it works when UAC is not enabled? It may not even be the UAC that is causing your problems. Are you able to run any other stsadm commands that would affect the database? If not, you may be simply getting an incorrect bubble up message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after two days investigating, I have the final result.

In SharePoint 2010, I installed a solution named "NewsGator.Core.wsp", it's a third party solution. When it's installed, some assemblies will be deployed to GAC. When you retract the solution you must notice that if the assemblies are used by w3wp.exe or not(process monitor can do this, you should first run it as administrator), if so your retract job will failed. It occurs in UAC enabled environment and will succeed if you use runas administrator to execute retract method.

So, firstly I doubted it as permission issue, using runas administrator can just make it work, then I came to ask the question above, but finally I found the cause by process monitor, after ended w3wp.exe or iisreset I got my retract job complete with successful.

Hope the above can help you.

Thanks very much for all your help, best regards.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a stab in the dark here - I'm guessing that when you say 'third assemblies', you're referring to a third party assembly that is running as part of some application, and you want that application / assembly to be able to install a sharepoint solution.  I.e., you're building some type of sharepoint solution management tool.

I could be way off on that, as it's just a guess.  But assuming that's true:

If you have UAC enabled, and you want this other assembly / application to be able to call stsadm, then you need to do run this other assembly / application as administrator.  Right-click on the exe that kicks it off (or shift-right click), then click 'run as administrator'.  That will cause the other application to run in the context of an administrator, so when it calls stsadm it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Run command prompt as Adminstrator

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I cannot use runas administrator, for it's cannot be invoked by third assemblies.